# Command prompt use on pen drive

Tags: command-line, window, command-prompt

I am using windows 7. In my pen drive there was some data. I had scanned it with Antivirus. There were some viruses and they were healed by Antivirus. But I am not able to see the files inside the Pen drive after that. I enabled hidden files visibility also. I tried to use Command prompt also with dir command, but it didn't work. dir is working for other drives, but not for the pen drive. In Pen drive, the used space is still the same as before the virus got in the pen drive. So I concluded data is still there, but I can't see it.

Can anyone tell me any other way to browse the data of pen drive since the data is really important?

Comment: Not really a programming question.  Not really sure what a "pan drive" is either.  In any case, probably a better fit for [SU].

Comment: Get a program like `Recuva` and it may help you to get your files back. See http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've got this once,try making system file visible
you can refer [this](http://arwebzone.com/show-hidden-files-and-folders/) for better understanding and to solve in case problem is what i suspect